# When does a finitely generated projective module surjects onto the ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $M$ be a non-zero, finitely generated projective module over a commutative integral domain $R$.

Is it necessarily true that there is an $R$-linear surjection $M\to R$ ? If this is not true in general, what if we also assume $R$ is Noetherian ?

I know this is true if $R$ is local as projective modules over local rings are free.

Of-course this is not true if we drop the integral domain assumption on $R$, for example $M=\mathbb Z/2\times 0$ is a finitely generated projective module over the Noetherian ring $R=\mathbb Z/2\times\mathbb Z/2$, but definitely $M$ cannot surject onto $R$ for cardinality reason. 
But with $R$ an integral domain, I have no counterexample.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R$ is a Dedekind domain, and $I$ a non-principal ideal of $R$, then $I$ is a projective module, but there is no $R$-module epimorphism $I\to R$.

Comment: Why is there no $R$-linear surjection $I\to R$ ?

Comment: Is the reason as follows ? If $I$ surjects onto $R$, then since $R$ is free, so $I\cong R\oplus N$ for some projective $R$-module $N$ and $N\ne 0$ since $I$ is not principal , so then $N$ has some positive constant rank say $n\ge 1$, and then $I_P\cong R_P^{n+1}$ for every prime ideal $P$ of $R$, contradicting that an ideal can only have rank $1$...

Comment: A homomorphism $I\to R$ must be given by $x\mapsto ax$ for some $a$ in the fraction field of $R$. @uno